# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое закругление сверстать?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

замучалась с бордер-радиусами, но так и не получилось

Comment: Можно на svg, можно на css, к примеру - абсолютно расположить div  огромного размера с border-radius где у родителя будет overflow, но на svg проще и чище

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно что-то такое сделать.. Первое значение `clip-path: ellipse(100%..` задаёт величину скругления. Уменьшение значения - увеличивает скругление.

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #DDD7D1;
  clip-path: ellipse(100% 100% at 50% 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: ellipse(100% 100% at 50% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: @Usti На здоровье  :)